# How to update country which is a string realtime in AsyncStorage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How to update country which is a string realtime in AsyncStorage? i have a state `const [country, setCountry] = useState(null);` and i have a userdata which is a object inside that userdata there is a object name user and inside user object there is country which is a string so how can I update that country to userdata.user.country realtime?

I am doing this beaccuse when i hit the api and then that country updates in database but its not updating in AsyncStorage user needs to re login to update it in AsyncStorage so how to update it instantly?

This is now userdata look like:

`LOG  {"message": "Successfully Signed In", "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI2M2Y4NmE2MjA5YjA1NDI5NDZlZjVjZjEiLCJpYXQiOjE2Nzc4MjkzNDh9.tmmN2aSgMGIad1A1IUtylUYDTx8eKNr-ZJykSc1Pais", "user": {"_id": "63f86a6209b0542946ef5cf1", "country": "", "email": "email@gmail.com", "name": "User1"}}`

```
 const [userdata, setUserdata] = useState(null);
 const userDataString = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user');
            const userData = JSON.parse(userDataString);
            setUserdata(userData);
```

Comment: Can you share your userData which your set in Asyncstorage?

Comment: @YakupMalikov i already shared check my update code that  LOG  message is userdata

Comment: you can use redux persist to store user Data in AsyncStorage. When there is a change in redux it change state of userdata.

Answer (score 0):

If you directly store the userData which you get from api, you can achieve it as below:

```
const changeUpdateCountry = async (userDataFromApi) => {
  await AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(userDataFromApi));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding Two Lines Of Code Works

```
  userdata.user.country = country; // Update country in userdata object
  await AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(userdata)); // Save
```